# Drag & Drop Shows Circle With Line Through It

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I think I have this set-up accurately, but anytime I try to drag a file onto my form it only shows a circle with a line through it. Which piece is not set-up properly?

```
private void Form1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.AllowDrop = true;
  this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragDrop);
  this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragEnter);
}
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) return;
  string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
    if (ext.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
        return;
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("This filetype is not allowed");
  }
}
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) return;
  string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
    if (ext.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
        return;
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("This filetype is not allowed");
  }
}
```

EDITED CODE

Comment: respond to DragEnter to test if you can accept that data type and set the cue

Comment: @Plutonix added that eventhandler and still same result? See edit.

Comment: You need to set what is allowed in the DragEventArgs

Comment: you forgot the last part: *set the cue*.

Comment: @JamesBarrass -- see edit, still same result

Comment: @Plutonix -- I am not following you? set the cue?

Comment: `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy` for example.  always examine event args to see what you have to work with both as input and for returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragDrop);
        this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragEnter);
    }
    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Dropping any file from windows explorer / my desktop etc shows a message box with the path and filename